# Need to efficiently join two tables; to calculate entry and exit times

Tags: sql, sql-server

Excuse my inexperience in this first post, but i am looking for assistance in solving what seems to be a simple problem. I have a table with entry and exit times for a group of users. Each record has a time stamp for each activity a user took while in side the application. Most specifically, i am interested in when they entered the app and when they left the app.

For example, each row has fields for: userid, application number, activity datetime. I've filtered the table to show only entry and exit records (as there are scores of activities for a user to choose from). Each user can have any number of entries and exits in one day. I need to find out how much time is spent within each session. Ideally, i would like to setup a structure that has the userid, app, entry and exit all in the same row but that's not what i have to start with. I have entries and exits on different rows.

What ive done so far--and this is proving to be inefficient--is to split entries and exits into two tables, use the exit table as my main table and add the entry table as a single valued subquery to be calculated line by line. This gets me the proper answer but it tales a few minutes to run and i will have to do this for several million records.

My ultimate goal is to calculate the total time between entries and exits for each user, per application, per session.

```
CREATE TABLE activity_table
(
    [userid] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [date_time] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [app_number] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [activity_type] [varchar](60) NOT NULL
) 

INSERT INTO activity_table
           ([userid]
           ,[date_time]
           ,[app_number]
           ,[activity_type]
           )
     VALUES
           ('tim','2020-03-19 18:22:23.000','webpage','exit'),
           ('tim','2020-03-19 19:06:20.000','webpage','exit'),
           ('tim','2020-03-19 19:08:15.000','webpage','exit'),
           ('tim','2020-03-24 17:05:05.000','webpage','exit'),
           ('tim','2020-03-24 17:11:47.000','webpage','exit'),
           ('tim','2020-03-24 17:52:29.000','webpage','exit'),
           ('tim','2020-03-24 17:58:00.000','webpage','exit'),
           ('tim','2020-03-25 10:32:30.000','webpage','exit'),
           ('tim','2020-03-27 14:31:37.000','webpage','exit'),
           ('tim','2020-03-19 17:19:54.000','webpage','entry'),
           ('tim','2020-03-19 18:38:26.000','webpage','entry'),
           ('tim','2020-03-19 19:07:08.000','webpage','entry'),
           ('tim','2020-03-24 16:47:22.000','webpage','entry'),
           ('tim','2020-03-24 17:05:13.000','webpage','entry'),
           ('tim','2020-03-24 17:27:13.000','webpage','entry'),
           ('tim','2020-03-24 17:52:36.000','webpage','entry'),
           ('tim','2020-03-25 10:19:49.000','webpage','entry'),
           ('tim','2020-03-27 14:26:07.000','webpage','entry')

with data1 as
(SELECT userid, 
       [date_time], 
       [app_number], 
       activity_type
FROM activity_table
WHERE userid IN('tim')
AND activity_type = 'entry'
),
data2 as (SELECT userid, 
       [date_time], 
       [app_number], 
       activity_type
FROM activity_table
WHERE userid IN('tim')
AND activity_type = 'exit'
)

select 
    a.*,
    (select top 1 date_time from data1 c 
        where c.date_time < a.date_time
                AND c.app_number = a.app_number
                AND CAST(c.[date_time] AS DATE) = CAST(a.[date_time] AS DATE))
from data2 a
```

What I want is this:

```
userid      entry              exit             app_number
tim         3/27/20 2:26 PM    3/27/20 2:31 PM  webpage
tim         3/25/20 10:19 AM   3/25/20 10:32 AM webpage
tim         3/24/20 4:47 PM    3/24/20 5:58 PM  webpage
tim         3/24/20 4:47 PM    3/24/20 5:52 PM  webpage
tim         3/24/20 4:47 PM    3/24/20 5:11 PM  webpage
tim         3/24/20 4:47 PM    3/24/20 5:05 PM  webpage
tim         3/19/20 5:19 PM    3/19/20 7:08 PM  webpage
tim         3/19/20 5:19 PM    3/19/20 7:06 PM  webpage
tim         3/19/20 5:19 PM    3/19/20 6:22 PM  webpage
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a tag for the database you are using.

Comment: Sorry it took a minute--i've supplied what i think might be helpful to you.

Comment: @MartinSmith I thought about that and perhaps that might work, i just worry that once this is input into a program like BI or tableau, that it breaks down. I'd prefer to have a bit more control over it if possible but i'll give that a try.

Comment: @JohnIrving You don't have any control over this because your schema does not capture "session". You have a log file that is missing important information. And since the app is recording this, you will need to account for missing "exits" - because crashes happen. I would even guess that you might need to account for missing "entries".

Comment: And if you're worried about efficiency, then it seems like a better approach is to materialize your session values into an actual table on a periodic basis (since this information will never change) rather than dynamically compute it every time it is needed.

Comment: @SMor - you still need the code to do that materialisation though which is basically the answer to the question asked (with some slight adjustment to only get sessions not previously materialised)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `LAG` to do this efficiently.

This assumes every exit will be preceded by an entry and you don't get consecutive entries of the same type for a user/app combination. If that does happen then any entries not immediately followed by an exit will be ignored and any exits not immediately preceded by an entry will be ignored.

```
WITH T
     AS (SELECT *,
                lag(date_time) OVER (PARTITION BY app_number, userid ORDER BY date_time) AS prev_date_time,
                lag(activity_type) OVER (PARTITION BY app_number, userid ORDER BY date_time) AS prev_activity_type
         FROM   activity_table
         WHERE  activity_type IN ( 'entry', 'exit' ))
SELECT userid,
       prev_date_time AS entry,
       date_time      AS [exit],
       app_number
FROM   T
WHERE  prev_activity_type = 'entry'
       AND activity_type = 'exit' 
ORDER BY entry DESC
```